# How to show image of the Product in custom email. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, frontend, backend

I'm getting my custom data from email function and also I'm getting the Product image URL to show it in mail now I tried many ways to show my image in email but its not working for me my custom email code is

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} 
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Name:</b> {{trans "%name" name=$name}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Email:</b> {{trans "%email" email=$email}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Phone Number:</b> {{trans "%pnumber" pnumber=$pnumber}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Offer Amount:</b> {{trans "%offeramount" offeramount=$offeramount}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Message:</b> {{trans "%message" message=$message}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Product Name:</b> {{trans "%product_name" product_name=$product_name}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">Product Price:</b> {{trans "%product_price" product_price=$product_price}}</p>
 <p align="center"><b style="color: #009900">URL:</b> {{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}</p>
 <!-- <img src="">{{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}</img> -->
 <!-- <img src="{{trans '%imgUrl' imgUrl=$imgUrl}}"> -->
 <img src="{{view url='%imgUrl'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

In email it shows like [image]

so the URL is comming perfectly but in case of **img** tag when I paste the URL in **img src="here"** then it is not working how can I set the URL in **img src**

Comment: have you tried like this <img src="{view url='%imgUrl'}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />

Comment: Sir how can I use **PHP** in **html** file???

Comment: Sir **<img src="{view url='%imgUrl'}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />** this is also not working for me

Comment: I see , this one should hopefully do the trick `<img src="{{view url=%imgUrl}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />`

Comment: Sir still not working

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong in your code, can you test passing static image like : `<img src="{{view url='hello.png'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />`

Comment: actually Sir I tried this code in my custom function from where I'm getting all this data at that place I check it in <img> tag when I echo this it works perfectly but in Email its not working. When I click on the URL as you can see in the above image then it shows me the image but in <img> tag its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91349/discussion-between-magefms-and-asad-khan).